# Does anyone know why minecraft villagers don't show armour

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

does anyone know why you can't summon a villager in minecraft with visible armour?

I'm using this command

> /summon villager ~ ~1 ~ {Profession:0,Career:1,ArmorItems:[{id:diamond_boots,Count:1b},{id:diamond_leggings,Count:1b},{id:diamond_chestplate,Count:1b},{id:diamond_helmet,Count:1b}]}

But it does not seem to have armour visible on it is there a fix to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about it: a villager looks nothing like a player in Minecraft. The armor won't fit them so the game does not display it. They still enjoy the protection given from the armor, but you just can't see it.

Answer (score -1):

Also prob. because they never intended to give villagers armor so they made no texture for armor on villagers, meaning that they still have it but it's not shown.

Just like if you have a texture pack and have mods installed, but the texture pack does not have textures for it(let's say IC2). The texture pack then does not show the machines or rubber trees but they are still in the world and loaded in.